# index a @MultiField spring-data-elasticsearch. Internationalization purposes

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I´m trying to index a multiField String attribute ("prueba") for multilingual purposes. My mapping is working with annotations

```
@MultiField(
      mainField = @Field(type = FieldType.String, store = true),
      otherFields = {
              @NestedField(dotSuffix = "cat", type = FieldType.String, store = true, indexAnalyzer = "catalan", searchAnalyzer = "catalan" ),
              @NestedField(dotSuffix = "ba", type = FieldType.String, store = true, indexAnalyzer = "basque", searchAnalyzer = "basque"),
              @NestedField(dotSuffix = "gal", type = FieldType.String, store = true, indexAnalyzer = "galician", searchAnalyzer = "galician"),
              @NestedField(dotSuffix = "en", type = FieldType.String, store = true, indexAnalyzer = "english", searchAnalyzer = "english")}
       )
protected String prueba;
```

The result mapping is :

```
,
           "prueba": {
              "type": "string",
              "store": true,
              "fields": {
                 "prueba.ba": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": true,
                    "analyzer": "basque"
                 },
                 "prueba.cat": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": true,
                    "analyzer": "catalan"
                 },
                 "prueba.en": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": true,
                    "analyzer": "english"
                 },
                 "prueba.gal": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": true,
                    "analyzer": "galician"
                 }
              }
           },
```

So, I index my object but the result is only...`

```
IndexQuery query = new IndexQuery();
query.setObject(itemTransparencia);
query.setType(subportal);

String id = this.elasticsearchOperations.index(query);

GET /item_transparencia/432/_search

{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "item_transparencia",
            "_type": "432",
            "_id": "AVTxEfvBhgYXtMQTaKx1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "subportal": "432",
               "titulo": null,
               "prueba": "prueba la tarta de mi casa",
               "subTitulo": null,
               "descripcion": null,
               "fechaIndexado": "2016-05-
```

I only get **"prueba": "prueba la tarta de mi casa"**.

-Could anybody help me to understand how can I index or get the nested fields from field "prueba"? 
-Does indexAnalyzer = "catalan", searchAnalyzer = "catalan" help me to index automatically to another lenguage?

thank so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multi-fields `prueba.ba`, `prueba.cat`, `prueba.en`, `prueba.gal` have been indexed but you won't see them in your source document.

You can now reference them directly in your queries (the analyzer declared in the mapping will be used as expected) and you'll get the results you expect. For instance, the following query should return you the document with id `AVTxEfvBhgYXtMQTaKx1`.

```
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "prueba.ba": "prueba"
      }
   }
}
```

However, just note that setting a language analyzer on a field won't translate the field's content into that analyzer's language, you need to do that yourself.

Comment: Thank you @Val. It´s the correct answer but  How can I insert my 4 different value languages in my  protected String "prueba" attribute? IndexQuery query = new IndexQuery();
query.setObject(itemTransparencia);
query.setType(subportal); Does it the correct way to do it? because in my object itemTransparencia has a setter setPrueba and it´s a single string value.

Comment: You'd need an [object field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html) for that, as a multi-field is not appropriate for what you're after. That can take the form of another class with 4 string fields referenced by your object.